# What could possibly prevent a file from showing up in Quick Access of Win10?

Tags: windows-10

The quick access of my windows explorer works just fine, which means all the files I opened or edited will show up there. But there's this one single word file that won't enter the quick access menu no matter what. I tried to edit its content and rename it but the issue remains. I checked its properties but can't find anything out of ordinary. It's nothing important and it doesn't bother me. But I'm quite curious what could be the possible cause of this one stubborn file that refuses to comply.

Comment: If you are willing, clear Quick Access, restart and try the file again.

Comment: do you have file extensions visible? ... make a copy of the file ... is the copy also stubborn?

Comment: @John That actually worked, thank you! I cleared Quick Access and now the file shows up without an issue. Though I still don't know why it didn't work before. Well, might be one of those weird system glitches I guess.

Comment: I posted an answer for you and hopefully you will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I have found to solve this issue is to clear Quick Access, restart and then check the file again.

To clear Quick Access, open Windows Explorer, right click on Quick Access (Upper Left) and select Options.

In the window that comes up, General Tab, click Clear.

Close out, restart, and test the file.

I trust this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've verified that the file has the same extension as files that do show up under `Recent Files`, it could be the file has its `Temporary` attribute set. I discovered this when I had a `.pdf` file that would show when viewing the folder but would disappear when searching the folder for `*.pdf`! It also affects whether or not the file appears under `Recent Files` when accessed.

Add the `Attributes` column to the details view of the containing folder:

[image]

### Search Results for *.jpg:

[image]

To clear the attribute:

1. Shift+right-click the file & select `Copy as path`
2. Shift+right click in the folder *background* & select `Open PowerShell window here`.
3. Type: `( gi<spcace><Ctrl+V><spcace>).Attributes -= 'Temporary'` ( Don't include `<` & `>` characters used to denote keystrokes )

   This should create a command that looks like:

   ```
   ( gi "c:\path\file.ext" ).Attributes -= 'Temporary'
   ```
4. Press `<Enter>` to execute
5. Check your `Explorer` window to verify the attribute was cleared.

Comment: That is very informative! Another user has already solved my issue and I promised to accept his answer, but thank you all the same for your detailed tips.